# NotesXSPDocument - Inserting a boolean breaks getDocument

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I have an XPage which has just broken due to (what should have been) a small change.

If I run (where document1 is NotesXSPDocument datasource) :

```
document1.replaceItem("ItemName", false); //or true, or any variable/formula that results in a boolean
```

followed by:

```
document1.getDocument(true);
```

I end up with an error

> [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesXspDocument.getDocument(boolean) null

This is on a new document (so not saved yet, which I've not tested, but might make a difference), hence I can't just set the field on the underlying doc.

It doesn't seem to be an artifact of anything else in the page, as a basic test page confirms it. It doesn't happen with anything (I've found) other than a boolean.

Any advice, other than just change the data type? I guess that's what I'll end up doing (along with a bug report) but I'd like to know I'm not missing something first.

Thanks

------------Test XSP code------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"><xp:this.data>
   <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Test" />
   </xp:this.data><xp:span style="font-weight:bold">
        Button 1 code:</xp:span><xp:br></xp:br>document1.replaceItemValue(&quot;Test&quot;,false);
<xp:br></xp:br>var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
<xp:br></xp:br>print(doc.toString());<xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Test 1" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.replaceItemValue("Test",false);
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
print(doc.toString());}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br><xp:span style="font-weight:bold">
    Button</xp:span><xp:span style="font-weight:bold"> 2</xp:span><xp:span style="font-weight:bold"> Code:</xp:span><xp:span style="font-weight:bold"></xp:span>&#160;<xp:br></xp:br>document1.replaceItemValue(&quot;Test&quot;,&quot;Test);<xp:br></xp:br>var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
<xp:br></xp:br>print(doc.toString());<xp:br></xp:br><xp:button value="Test 2" id="button2">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.replaceItemValue("Test","Test");
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
print(doc.toString());}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button></xp:view>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a look in the stack trace you will see the following:

```
....
NotesException: Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector
    lotus.domino.local.Document.NreplaceItemValue(Native Method)
    lotus.domino.local.Document.replaceItemValue(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.applyChangesToDoc(DominoDocument.java:1698)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.applyChanges(DominoDocument.java:1649)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.getDocument(DominoDocument.java:544)
    com.ibm.xsp.script.WrapperDominoEx$fct_DominoDocument.call(WrapperDominoEx.java:254)
....
```

The problem is that you use the *replaceItemValue* method with an unsupported data type.

Here is a list of all allowed data types:

- String Text
- Integer Number
- Double Number
- DateTime  Date-time item
- java.util.Vector with String, Integer, Double, or DateTime elements Multi-value text, number, or date-time item
- Item Same data type as the Item

The error is raised in the moment the backend document is synchronized with the datasource document. That's why it fails while calling *document1.getDocument(true)*.

Hope this helps

Sven

**EDIT:**
Why are you setting the value to *false*?

Comment: Figures. I guess I'll have to use a number instead then. I'm not really setting it to false, just for the test / example.

Comment: +1 exactly, boolean is not legit Notes item type. by convention it should be 0/1 (number) or ""/"1" (string).